# NOT IN filter does not work when querying External Object

Tags: apex, soql, filters, externalobjects

I have an external object from which I want to retrieve certain values avoiding some other ones depending on certain conditions.

The problem is that when I apply the NOT IN filter like in the following

```
SELECT Id, VALUE__c, DESCRIPTION__c, FROM ZSDFMarcolor__x WHERE VALUE__c NOT IN :valuesToAvoidLIST
```

It doesn't work and I can see that query is getting me the same values I specify not to retrieve.

Is this some kind of bug or unexpected behavior with external objects? Because I haven't worked that much with them and I don't know what to do.

Regards,

Comment: Have you tried to check if `valuesToAvoidLIST` is populated correctly? or if the query is fetching the same results when you hardcode the values in the query like `NOT IN ('value1', 'value2')`?

Comment: Hi @arut Yes I tried fetching the variable and also hardcoring the values but still not working

Comment: Checked the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_limits.htm?q=EXTERNAL) but do not see "NOT IN" listed under unsupported operators. I'm trying to repro this in my org and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Is there a need for escaping characters in `valuesToAvoidLIST` (refer [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_quotedstringescapes.htm))? Also, are you seeing the same behavior when querying fields other than `VALUE__c`?

Comment: what is the type of external data source you are using? I used the external data source mentioned in [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quickstart-lightning-connect/quickstart-lightning-connect2) and the query `SELECT Id, categoryID__c, categoryName__c FROM Category__x where Id NOT IN ('x005j000000Q7grAAC')` works as expected.

Comment: I checked with our product team on this behavior. The IN operator is sometimes translated to OR conditions. NOT IN would need to be handled consistently with NOT and AND conditions. Can you please have a salesforce support case filed for further investigation?

Comment: Hi @Swetha. The external data source type is 'Salesforce Connect: Custom—Vigience_Dev.EnterpriseGateway'. I've also tried using AND Field__c != 'value' for each value but still not working as expected. I'll open a SF case as soon as my PM allows me to but thanks for all your help!